# Typeahead.js let the user add an element not present in the list

Tags: javascript, typeahead

I am currently using Typeahead.js to offer autocompletion of tags in a project. Everytime a tag is autocompleted, the typeahead textbox is cleared and the chosen element is saved in an array of strings.

While still offering this feature, I would like to add an "Add new tag" element in the list of suggestions. The user could click on this extra element if the written tag is not in the suggestions list (note that this extra element should still be shown even if suggestions are present in the list). This would save the value found in the textbox and clear the typeahead textbox afterward.

I have tried using the footer template to add this "Add new tag" element to the bottom of the list, like this :

```
$('#myTypeaheadInput').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true
    },
    {
      name: 'tags',
      displayKey: 'value',
      source: substringMatcher(tags),
      templates: {
        footer: '<div class="addNew">Add new tag</div>'
      }
    })
```

But I ended up trying (and failing) to trigger an autocomplete event myself, which is probably not the best way to do it.

If this is possible, how should I be adding this "Add new tag" element in the bottom of the suggestions list?